# Programmatically printing a block

Tags: views, blocks

So far I have been using this code, which works fine to print third-party module blocks.

```
<?php
    $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'og_members-block_1');
    print render($block);
?>
```

However, now I am trying to print a block that lives within my theme folder and I can't seem to figure out how to do that. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a way to programmatically print a block in a tpl file.

For 'module' defined blocks you can use `block_load()` see: [block_load op api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/block_load/7)

If you have a block defined through the block interface, it is called a custom block you can use `block_custom_block_get($bid)` see: [block_custom_block_get() on api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/block_custom_block_get/7)

```
$block = block_custom_block_get(1);
$content = $block['body'];
```

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be confusing things a bit.

Your method that you use in your code example is pretty sounds, it invokes `hook_block_view` for the desire module with a specific block delta. This method works fine because the only way to create blocks is through the hooks that the block module has defined.

This means that a theme can't create a block and you can't load a block from the theme. You would instead need to implement it in a module. Doing so would allow you to use the method you yourself has described.

Comment: @googletrop, Thanks again for the help, so that means that there is not way to programmatically print a block from within a tpl page ? Not even with a Query?

Comment: There is a difference between creating a block (which is done with hook_block in a module) and printing a block in a tpl.php (which can be done like you described yourself). To write a custom module which implements hook_block, see [hook_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6) and [block_example.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example--block_example.module/6).

Answer (score 3):

It's work for me in Drupal 7.

```
$block = block_load('block', 'block_id');
$output =_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
$res_output = drupal_render($res_output);
print render($res_output);
```

Comment: There is a mistake in your code. It should be `$res_output = drupal_render($output);` (you are repeating `$res_output`)

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically printing a block in tpl file.

```
$view = views_get_view("block-name");
print $view->preview("block");
```