# Call counter module in a page

Tags: 6, theming

How can I place visitor stats in a page from [Counter](http://drupal.org/project/counter) module in Drupal 6?
I'm looking for the php Code. Maybe it can be done with:

```
<?php print theme(); ?>
```

but I don't know the exact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, the Counter module shows that information in a block. If you want show the content of that block in a page, without setting the block to appear in that page, you could use the following code.

```
$block = module_invoke('counter', 'block', 'view');
if (isset($block['content'])) {
  print $block['content'];
}
```

Keep in mind that the Counter module shows the content of that block to users with the "view counter" permission. If you want to show that content to users without that permission, you need to use different code.
Keep in mind that executing that code causes many SQL queries to be executed; some of those queries update some database tables. It is probably better to cache the output returned for that block.

Considering this, it is probably better to make the block provided from the Counter module in that page.

Comment: Really Thanks kiamlaluno♦, I'll have your advises in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Counter creates a block that you can then position. If you need to do it programmatically, see this question and answer: [Programmatically printing a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5775/programmatically-printing-a-block)

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine too:

```
$tvisit = db_result(db_query("SELECT counter_id FROM {counter_today} ORDER BY counter_id DESC")); 
$cvisit = db_result(db_query("SELECT `counter_value` FROM `counter_data` WHERE `counter_data`.`counter_name` = 'site_counter'")); ?>
```