# How do I insert the title of the block between two Views fields?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, theming

A designer has sent me a very cool design, and I don't know which is the **.tpl** file I need to override.

[image]

Basically, I need to put the title of the block between two fields of a view. The view is already a header of another view, and it displays only one record.

Other (bad) alternatives I see:

- Do some positioning tricks with CSS.
- Create a *custom text* field and style it like if it was the block title, and then hide the block title.

Comment: do you have multiple results in that view? or is it just one? plus: what have you used for that mockup? it looks great!

Comment: It's only one result because it's a header of another view.

Comment: For the mockup I've used a free account on http://moqups.com

Comment: I'd be very tempted by the second of your 'bad' alternatives. Views can be a bit mean with what is filtered in the Global: Custom text field, though for this custom css would see you right. If you are just using one row, you can exclude some of the rows from display and then pop a Global: Text area in the Header with a more liberal Text format. The Global: Text area makes available all your first row field values as tokens (which for you is only row). **All of which said** I do get that for some folks, code is preferable to fancy/hacky config, e.g. because of version control issues.

Comment: Code is preferable but I think I could override *views-view-field.tpl* for that. The problem I see is that styling a custom text as a title may cause me other troubles.

Comment: @Pere, while it is solvable by editing templates, are you sure you need a View for this? It's gonna take some preprocess hacks just for that, you're probably better off just building the block on your own unless you *really really* need Views.

Comment: I'm not sure I really need Views. I hoped there was a better solution in Views for that, but if not...

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Views block area](http://drupal.org/project/views_block_area)

> This module exposes all available blocks as a views area. This way you
>   can add any block inside a footer or header from your view.

Also there is [Views Hacks](http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks)

Or i would do it with [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) by adding a field and print the block there with https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/14354/4471

Comment: The first two solutions won't work for that, I think. The third could work, but I was looking for a proper solution

Answer (score 2):

From here: http://themery.com/book/export/html/91 you need to create a file named like block--MODULE--DELTA.tpl.php

So for a views block I believe it's block--views--VIEWNAME-DISPLAYNAME.tpl.php

Comment: To pull individual fields out of the view in a block template may be tricky, though so your alternative suggestion of hiding the title and generating it as a field inside the view might work better in practice.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with @Alfred here. What you're looking for is actually printing some fields, then the title, then more fields. Editing the template should be enough. Although I'd copy over and edit the views-view-unformatted.tpl.php template from the Views module.

Comment: thanks, that was. But I cannot print the block title because $title is empty. And I would need to theme only the header display, which seems is not possible: views-view-unformatted--VIEWNAME--block.tpl is printing the display as a row.

Comment: Confirmed: Overriding *views-view-unformatted.tpl.php* cannot alter the block title