# Custom search box to be included in a view

Tags: 7, search, views

I am using the search box provided from the [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module. It works great. I want to know if there is any way by which i can include the search box in a view which i have created. Regards

PS: I tried this but no effect:

```
<?php
  $block = module_invoke('custom_search', 'block_view', 'custom_search');
  print render($block); 
?>
```

It displays nothing

Based on below comments i tried doing this:

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('custom_search', 'block', 'view', 0);
print $block['content'];
  ?>
```

Comment: where did you tried this code? and how ?

Comment: i wrote it in the header of view as Global:PHP

Comment: See this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/14354/4471

Comment: Also is it true as the below answer says that "You can not include search box generated by custom search module into views"....?

Comment: Do you mean to just display the block on a view page? Or do you want to search on the view results?

Comment: display on a view page

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to filter views result, then adding **Custom Search** block will not work.
To get this work you need to add **Global: Combine fields filter** under Add filter criteria, then select fields on which you want to filter the result from **Choose fields to combine for filtering**. Expose this field to display a search text field. Please check screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not include search box generated by custom search module into views, but you can add exposed filter into views to implement search functionality in the views.

To implement search functionality in the views

- Add "field" in the filter and choose "Contains" from the operator list
- Exposed field in the filer

It will display a search box for that field in the views and work nicely for searching.

Answer (score 0):

You may just try to expose the "Custom Search 1"-block found in the block-list under `admin/structure/block`. In the configuration settings for the block `admin/structure/block/manage/custom_search_blocks/1/configure` you can set the visibility settings for the block to your views-page by inserting your path to the view page.

Comment: nice idea...will look into...